# Angular-ui-tree shows an extra line when last child has children

Tags: css, nodes, treenode, angular-ui-tree

I have tried different CSS tricks and hacks but can't seem to get my way around this. So, I have a UI tree with connectors as shown in below:

https://jsfiddle.net/jqaw41mo/

```css
div.panel:first-child {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

div.treeview {
  min-width: 100px;
  min-height: 100px;
  max-height: 256px;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  color: #369;
  border: solid 1px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

div.treeview ul:first-child:before {
  display: none;
}

.treeview,
.treeview ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  color: #369;
}

.treeview ul {
  margin-left: 1em;
  position: relative
}

.treeview ul ul {
  margin-left: .5em
}

.treeview ul:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-left: 1px solid;
  /* creates a more theme-ready standard for the bootstrap themes */
  bottom: 15px;
}

.treeview li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 1em;
  line-height: 2em;
  font-weight: 700;
  position: relative
}

.treeview ul li:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid;
  margin-top: -1px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1em;
  left: 0
}

.tree-indicator {
  margin-right: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.treeview li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.treeview li button,
.treeview li button:active,
.treeview li button:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->

<div class="container">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">Treeview List</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <!-- TREEVIEW CODE -->
      <ul class="treeview">
        <li><a href="#">Tree</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Branch</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Branch</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Stick</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Stick</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Stick</a>
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Twig</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Twig</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Twig</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Twig</a>
                      <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Leaf</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Leaf</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Leaf</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Twig</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Twig</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Stick</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Branch</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Branch</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

This look fine but the problem arises when the last child of a particular node has a child. The problem is recreated in the link below:

https://jsfiddle.net/3vxjerg2/

```css
div.panel:first-child {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

div.treeview {
  min-width: 100px;
  min-height: 100px;
  max-height: 256px;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  color: #369;
  border: solid 1px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

div.treeview ul:first-child:before {
  display: none;
}

.treeview,
.treeview ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  color: #369;
}

.treeview ul {
  margin-left: 1em;
  position: relative
}

.treeview ul ul {
  margin-left: .5em
}

.treeview ul:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-left: 1px solid;
  /* creates a more theme-ready standard for the bootstrap themes */
  bottom: 15px;
}

.treeview li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 1em;
  line-height: 2em;
  font-weight: 700;
  position: relative
}

.treeview ul li:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid;
  margin-top: -1px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1em;
  left: 0
}

.tree-indicator {
  margin-right: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.treeview li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.treeview li button,
.treeview li button:active,
.treeview li button:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->

<div class="container">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">Treeview List</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <!-- TREEVIEW CODE -->
      <ul class="treeview">
        <li><a href="#">Tree</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Branch</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Branch</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Stick</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Stick</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Stick</a>
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Twig</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Twig</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Twig</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Twig</a>
                      <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Leaf</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Leaf</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Leaf</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Twig</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Twig</a>
                      <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Leaf</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Leaf</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Leaf</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Stick</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Branch</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Branch</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

As seen, the last twig has three leaves, the `border-left` on the `last-child` property did not help my case.

Is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line is generated by the border of `.treeview ul:before` [pseudo element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before). Since its height is not defined it will have the height of the entire `ul`, and its border will be to the left of the entire `ul`.

In order to shorten this border you can define the `height` of the `:before` pseudo element.

If your HTML is static you can just add classes to the problematic `ul` elements and define a `height` to the `.treeview ul.problematic:before` selector.

https://jsfiddle.net/kc5jx1wy/

```css
div.panel:first-child {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

div.treeview {
  min-width: 100px;
  min-height: 100px;
  max-height: 256px;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  color: #369;
  border: solid 1px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

div.treeview ul:first-child:before {
  display: none;
}

.treeview,
.treeview ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  color: #369;
}

.treeview ul {
  margin-left: 1em;
  position: relative
}

.treeview ul ul {
  margin-left: .5em
}

.treeview ul:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-left: 1px solid;
  /* creates a more theme-ready standard for the bootstrap themes */
  bottom: 15px;
}

.treeview ul.problematic:before {
  height: 238px;
}

.treeview li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 1em;
  line-height: 2em;
  font-weight: 700;
  position: relative
}

.treeview ul li:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid;
  margin-top: -1px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1em;
  left: 0
}

.tree-indicator {
  margin-right: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.treeview li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.treeview li button,
.treeview li button:active,
.treeview li button:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->

<div class="container">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">Treeview List</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <!-- TREEVIEW CODE -->
      <ul class="treeview">
        <li><a href="#">Tree</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Branch</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Branch</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Stick</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Stick</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Stick</a>
                  <ul class="problematic">
                    <li><a href="#">Twig</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Twig</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Twig</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Twig</a>
                      <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Leaf</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Leaf</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Leaf</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Twig</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Twig</a>
                      <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Leaf</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Leaf</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Leaf</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Stick</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Branch</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Branch</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, if your HTML is generated dynamically you'll have to use JavaScript to calculate the needed `height` for each `ul` and apply the CSS with code.

Comment: Thank you for your inputs. My HTML is generated dynamically, I'll calculate the height dynamically as per your suggestion.